# UIScrollview with no scrolling just zoom

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiscrollview

I have an app that has a bunch of UIScrollViews inside of a UIScrollView.

I can scroll back and forth and then zoom in on sub UIScrollview items in the main UIScrollview.

I would like to remove the scroll (left/right) of the main UIScrollView while keeping the scrolling (zoom) of the sub scrollviews.

When I disable scrolling on the main UIScrollview, (mainScroll.scrollEnabled = NO) I can no longer zoom in the subviews.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Figured it out... it works fine on the device, not in the simulator: